# Wait for a signal with parameters in synchronously mode

Tags: signals-slots, qt4.8

The following code works fine when I need to wait for a signal in sychronous mode.

```
    QEventLoop signalWaitLoop;

    connect(&emmiter, SIGNAL(signalValue(quint8)), &signalWaitLoop, SLOT(quit()));

    emmiter.sendSignal();
    signalWaitLoop.exec();
```

How can I nicely retrieve the emmited value *(quint8)* from the signal?

Answer (score 0):

Make your own class:

```
    class MyEventLoop : public QEventLoop
    {
        Q_OBJECT
    public:
        MyEventLoop(QObject * parent = 0)
           : QEventLoop(parent) {}
    public slots:
        void mySlot(quint8 value) {
            // something with value
            quit();
        }
    }

    MyEventLoop signalWaitLoop;
    connect(&emmiter, SIGNAL(signalValue(quint8)), &signalWaitLoop, SLOT(mySlot(quint8)));
```